# Bash asterisk omits files that start with '.'?

Tags: bash, file, loops, directory

I'm using a bash script to iterate over all files in a directory.  But the loop is skipping over files that begin with a '.' such as '.bashrc'  I'm not sure if .bashrc is failing the file test or is being omitted from the wildcard '*'.  I've tried double quotes around "$item" but same result.  How can I make this loop include .bashrc files?

```
id=0     
cd $USERDIR
for item in *
do
    if [[ -f $item ]]; then
        cdir[$id]=$item
        id=$(($id+1))
        echo $item
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 17):

It's not the *loop* omitting those files, it's the expansion of `*` by the shell. If you want the dotfiles as well, use:

```
for item in .* *
```

From the `bash` manpage:

> When a pattern is used for pathname expansion, the character `"."` at the start of a name or immediately following a slash must be matched *explicitly,* unless the shell option `dotglob` is set.

That last sentence on the `dotglob` option may seem to be useful but you should be wary of changing options that may affect later code. The safest way to use them is to ensure you set them back to their original values, something like:

```
rest_cmd=$(shopt -p dotglob)  # Get restoration command
shopt -s dotglob              # Set option
for item in * ; do
    blah blah blah
done
${rest_cmd}                   # Restore option
```

But, in this case, I'd just stick with the explicit use of `.* *` since that's an easy solution.

Comment: great.  more info here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html  
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html#sect_02_03_02

Comment: Don't forget that `.*` will match the current and parent directories, `.` and `..`, which can cause problems depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Keith: yes, not so in this case since it's filtering with `-f` to only process files, but I've been caught in infinite loops before by continuously processing the `.` "subdirectory" :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can set `dotglob`

```
shopt -s dotglob
for item in *; do echo "$item"; done
```

Comment: this appears to address the specific issue I am having here. From the shopt man page: "dotglob If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a ‘.’ in the results of pathname expansion." but do I have to unset shopt after using it?

Comment: @user3143122, no you should _not_ unset it. You should restore it to its previous value as per the latter part of my answer. Unsetting it when it was originally set is as bad as leaving it set when it was originally unset.

Comment: If you set the `dotglob` in your bash script, the setting only applies to your script, it's not affecting your shell settings

Comment: @paxdiablo, understood, it is best to put it back to what it was. but from what I've read the default is unset. does changing it affect the shell itself, or just shopt's behavior in my script?

Comment: looks like my ques was anticipted :)

Comment: In the script if it's running as a sub shell (ie, not with `. myscript` or `source myscript`), shell otherwise. But you may still want to localise it from code later on in that script. Safest course is to keep all effects as local as possible.

Comment: So if I put 'shopt -s dotglob' immediately before 'do' and 'shopt -u dotglob' immediately after 'done' is that safe?  How else does one localize these builtin shell options?  Or is 'rest_cmd=$(shopt -p dotglob)' the only way?

Comment: This is more useful because it directly solves the problem without paxdiablo's first suggestion of * .* which isn't a good solution for the OP's problem. paxdiablo's suggestion about restoring the glob options, however, is a useful addition.